# react-navigation: set the type of screenProps in HeaderProps in Flow

Tags: flowtype, react-navigation

I'm passing custom properties to the screens using the `screenProps` field of `HeaderProps` [as per docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options#Two-Ways-to-specify-each-option).

I would like Flow to check its type, too. So I created a custom `MyHeaderProps` which looks like:

```
declare type MyHeaderProps = {
  screenProps: ScreenProps,
  scene: HeaderProps.scene,
  scenes: HeaderProps.scenes,
  navigation: HeaderProps.navigation,
}
```

This solution is not very smart though, as it doesn't update with react-navigation. So I tried:

```
declare type MyHeaderProps = {
  screenProps: ScreenProps,
  ...HeaderProps,
}
```

But with no success (ie: an error like `headerProps.whatever` is not detected).

EDIT: correct the union type notation as suggested in the comments and document the new error.

Even a union type doesn't work:

```
declare type MyHeaderProps = {
  screenProps: ScreenProps,
} | HeaderProps
```

This way when I try to access `const { navigation, screenProps } = headerProps` it says there's no `navigation` property.

Comment: Your last type def is an intersection type, which is the opposite of a union. For a type whose inhabitants are objects of different but known shape you need a union type which is denoted by `|`.

Comment: wow, this makes me feel an idiot :(
But if I fix it, it will throw errors everywhere I do `const { navigation, screenprops } = headerProps`. Doesn't find `navigation` property.

Comment: Don't, these are just terms and maybe an intersection type is better suited to your problem. I don't know react well enough to help, sorry.